# problems after Cloud SQL Administration API update

Tags: google-cloud-sql

First, after I updated the Cloud SQL Admin API via Eclipse, I noticed that some of my classes broke. Apparently the API had changed.

Specifically, methods in ExportContext had changed; setDatabase() was no longer present and had been replaced by setDatabases() and setTable() had been replaced by setSqlExportOptions().

BUT, the problem is, after updating my code to the new API, it won't run.

New Code:

```
    ExportContext exportContext = new ExportContext()
            .setFileType("SQL")
            .setDatabases( Arrays.asList(srcDatabase) )
            .setSqlExportOptions( new SqlExportOptions().setTables( new ArrayList<String>(tableNames) ) )
            .setUri(dumpUri);
```

Here is the exception:

```
    (com.google.api.services.sqladmin.model.ExportContext.setFileType(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/services/sqladmin/model/ExportContext;)
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.services.sqladmin.model.ExportContext.setFileType(Ljava/lang/String;)Lcom/google/api/services/sqladmin/model/ExportContext;
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The new version of the Cloud SQL Admin API, `v1beta4`, was recently released and it includes a few changes like the ones you are saying. For example `setSqlExportOptions` needs to be set for exporting data in `SQL` format.

The old version, `v1beta3` is still available. My guess is that you never specified an API version and eclipse automatically generated the client code for the latest version. Make sure you specify which version you want to use.

Comment: I understand. But when I try v4 and explicitcity set that version in the path as per the only Java example I could find, I still always get the above exception.

Comment: i did specify v1beta4 with setServicePath () and still get same error. Is there another setting? could it be a credential issue?

Comment: is this the correct service path:.setServicePath("sql/v1beta4/projects/")